# How to project a 3-d object onto a 2-d plane in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have a group of twenty or so lines that form a shape (a "birdy").  I am currently rotating it about the y-axis (the "up" axis) on top of a "mirror".  Here is a screen shot:

[[image: complex shape rotating on yellow mirror]]
What I want to do is to project the rotating shape onto the xy plane of the "mirror" (the yellow plane) by just ignoring the z components, so you would just see the 2-d projection of the shape as it looks from its side.

Currently, my plan of attack is as follows:

1. Keep the original shape in 3-d form so the rotation works right.  I think if I reduce it down to 2-d at this point, the rotation won't be right.
2. Rotate the 3-d archetype about the y-axis, but don't display it yet.  Here is the code I'm currently using:

---

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
var mat = m.makeRotationY(base.ONE_DEGREE * 0.2);
birdyGroupClone.applyMatrix(mat);
```

3. loop over the individual lines in the group, via the children array, and go to geometry.vertices and set the z component to zero.
4. Finally, render these 2-d lines (as a group) onto the xy-plane.

I am stuck on point 3, because when I multiply the lines in the group by the matrix, I can't find the intermediary rotation results anywhere in the heirarchy.  The vertices themselves are not affected -- they still contain the canonical "root" values.

Here is the relevant portion of object heirarchy for the group taken from a Chrome browser debug session:

```
birdyGroupClone: THREE.Object3D
    __webglActive: true
    __webglInit: true
    _listeners: Object
    _modelViewMatrix: THREE.Matrix4
    _normalMatrix: THREE.Matrix3
    castShadow: false
    children: Array[30]
        0: THREE.Line
        1: THREE.Line
        2: THREE.Line
        3: THREE.Line
        4: THREE.Line
        __webglActive: true
        __webglInit: true
        _listeners: Object
        _modelViewMatrix: THREE.Matrix4
        _normalMatrix: THREE.Matrix3
        castShadow: false
        children: Array[0]
        eulerOrder: (...)
        frustumCulled: true
        geometry: THREE.Geometry
            __colorArray: Float32Array[6]
            __lineDistanceArray: Float32Array[2]
            __vertexArray: Float32Array[6]
            __webglColorBuffer: WebGLBuffer
            __webglInit: true
            __webglLineCount: 2
            __webglLineDistanceBuffer: WebGLBuffer
            __webglVertexBuffer: WebGLBuffer
            _listeners: Object
            boundingBox: null
            boundingSphere: THREE.Sphere
            colors: Array[0]
            colorsNeedUpdate: false
            dynamic: true
            elementsNeedUpdate: false
            faceVertexUvs: Array[1]
            faces: Array[0]
            groupsNeedUpdate: false
            hasTangents: false
            id: 160
            lineDistances: Array[0]
            lineDistancesNeedUpdate: false
            morphColors: Array[0]
            morphNormals: Array[0]
            morphTargets: Array[0]
            name: ""
            normalsNeedUpdate: false
            skinIndices: Array[0]
            skinWeights: Array[0]
            tangentsNeedUpdate: false
            type: "Geometry"
            uuid: "55EE9F6D-0DD1-4581-817A-9E324EC5225D"
            uvsNeedUpdate: false
            vertices: Array[2]
                0: THREE.Vector3  <-- These are unaffected by the rotation
                    x: -0.616     <--  Where are the transformed coordinates?
                    y: 0
                    z: -0.68
                    __proto__: THREE.Vector3
                1: THREE.Vector3
                    x: -0.5
                    y: 0
                    z: -1
                    __proto__: THREE.Vector3
                length: 2
```

This is after doing a rotation.  Where are the intermediate post-transform vertices, that I can use for my transformation "pipeline" (to take the 2-d projections).  Are they only reflected in the browser canvas?

So my questions are:

1. Does my plan of attack sound right, or is there a better way to do it?
2. If yes, how do I access the results of intermediate transformations so I can apply a "pipeline" of processing?

Many thanks.

Comment: 1. Do you want a [properly-rendered](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html) mirror? 2. You need to understand the difference between `Object3D.applyMatrix( mat )`, which modifies the object transform, and `Geometry.applyMatrix( mat )`, which modifies the geometry vertices. Look at the source code so you understand what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will definitely investigate these ideas.  Part of the reason for posting the question is I always feel like I'm missing some existing api that does what I need "magically".  Sounds like I may have to do a little "thinking" on this one.  I will post any solution I do find.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the input from WestLangley, I was able to find a solution.  Now that I've done it, I realize a better of way of describing my problem was to say I wanted to project the *shadow* of the 3-d object onto a plane.

I basically have to do a transform on each of the line geometries individually as opposed to doing it on the group.  Doing it this way, the vertices of the lines *are* updated, and then I can proceed with the rest of my plan as described previously.

Here is what my code looks like:

```js
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
var mat = m.makeRotationY(base.ONE_DEGREE * 0.2);

// loop over each line and transform individually
// I had to do in a try catch block, but you shouldn't have to
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < birdyGroupClone.children.length; i++) {
        birdyGroupClone.children[i].geometry.applyMatrix(mat);
    }
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error=' + e);
    return false;
}

// Create a new Shadow group on each render
// make sure to remove the old one, otherwise your frame rate will bog down
// I had trouble with simply cloning birdyGroupClone because it doesn't
// deep copy all the way down (?), so I create anew each time.
factory.xyProjectionMesh.remove(birdyGroupShadow);
birdyGroupShadow = new THREE.Object3D();

//remove z-component from birdyGroupClone vertices
for (var i = 0; i < birdyGroupClone.children.length; i++) {
    var line, lineGeometry, vertex;

    lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    vertex = birdyGroupClone.children[i].geometry.vertices[0];
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertex.x, vertex.y, 0));
    vertex = birdyGroupClone.children[i].geometry.vertices[1];
    lineGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vertex.x, vertex.y, 0));

    line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, birdyGroupClone.children[i].material);

    birdyGroupShadow.add(line);
};

birdyGroupShadow.position.set(0, 0, 0);
this.xyProjectionMesh.add(birdyGroupShadow);
```

Maybe this isn't the prettiest way to do it, but it works.

Here is a screen shot showing the result.  Note, how it exists entirely on the plane and has no "depth":

[image]